# compute the Kähler moduli of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, mirror-symmetry

Say given elliptic curve $ \{ (x,y) | y^2 = (x^2-1)(x^2-k^2) \}$, what is the right form of the K$\ddot{a}$hler form and how to compute the K$\ddot{a}$hler moduli of this elliptic curve? Thank you.

Comment: Put it into the more usual form of $y^2=f(x)$ with $f$ cubic (see Cassels book on elliptic curves for how to do this; Cassels gives lots of transformations for getting general genus 1 curves into this form, including the type you have here) and then it's just $dy/x$ (with the new coordinates).

Comment: Kevin, you have described an element of $H^0(\Omega^1)$.  Isn't the Kahler form a 2-form, giving the hyperplane class in $H^2$ (so it should be a (1,1) form on the elliptic curve, not a (1,0) form).

Comment: @Dan: $H^{1,1}$ is 1 dimensional. You just have to write down the Kähler form. Then the Kähler moduli is just a 1 dimensional space given by scalings of the Kähler form.

Comment: @Emerton: sounds like I misunderstood the question. I'd delete my comment were it not for the fact that it would make your comment look meaningless :-) Yes, I described a global holomorphic 1-form. I thought these were called Kaehler 1-forms by some people and assumed this was what the questioner was asking about.

Comment: Can't we make use of Kevin's comment? Take his (1,0) form \alpha and set \omega = i * \alpha \wedge \overline{\alpha}. Then \omega is a real (1,1)-form, and Kahler if it is non-degenarate (and positive, but take -\omega if it's negative).

Comment: Kevin Buzzard, yes, the coherent sheaf of (1,0) forms is called the sheaf of Kahler differentials.  Kevin Lin, you are right, the Kahler moduli here is just one-dimensional.  Gunnar, Yes, and I think the correct sign is $-i \alpha \wedge \overline{\alpha}$.  (Think of
$\alpha$ as being $dz = dx + i dy$; then $-i dz d\overline{z}$
is a positive multiple of $dx\wedge dy$.)

Comment: There is a missing wedge in the above: I should have written $-i dz \wedge d\overline{z}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curve you wrote in equations lies in C^2, while the "elliptic curve" of your text is presumably a compact projective variety -- meaning you imagine making your equations homogeneous (or even quasi-homogeneous) and considering the closure of the set of points described by your equation in a (quasi-)projective plane.  Not every "homogenization" will lead to an elliptic curve (Calabi-Yau) upon compactification, so you have to do this correctly (as noted by Kevin Buzzard above).

Having said that, the answer is that every projective variety is also Kahler:  just restrict e.g. the Fubini-Study(-like) Kahler form.  In plain English, since a Kahler form on a complex curve is just a volume form, the volume of the compact curve inside projective space gives you your answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am still confused with the Fubini-Study like Kahler form here. We can choose a volume form (Kahler form) up to scaling, so the volume (Kahler moduli) will be a multiple of some area A. On the other side, the complex structure is normalised as 
$\tau$ ( say our lattice is $Z+Z\tau$). By the mirror map, $\tau \arrow \rho= b + iA$, my question is how can I fix $b$ and $A$?

Comment: 
You're thinking of mirror symmetry now, not pure geometry.  In mirror symmetry, the Kahler form is "complexified," referring to a sum of a general (1,1)-form (with no positivity conditions) plus "i" times a geometric Kahler form (which lives in the [real] Kahler cone).  More generally, when you integrate the exponential of this form over the surface (i.e. take the pairing with a class in H_2) you get a complex number of modulus less than one, which is the weighting factor for the Gromov-Witten invariant in that homology class.  Ideally, the sum over all such numbers will converge.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Let me put the question in another way, how can one verify some phenomenon is mirror symmetry of dimension one? I am reading "motives from diffraction" by Jan Stienstra http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511485 

Comment: That question ("some phenomenon") is a bit vague.  For more you can read Kontsevich's 1994 ICM paper or this paper by Polishchuk et al:  http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/9801.5119

Comment: The updated link to _Categorical Mirror Symmetry: The Elliptic Curve_ in Eric's comment is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801119